# Why is the for loop not working?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm sure this has something to do with that it's nearly 5 AM...and that I'm missing something obvious.

Here is my code:

```
var dayInMonth = 2,
    lastDayNum = 30;

console.log(dayInMonth, (dayInMonth > lastDayNum)); // displays "2 false"

for(dayInMonth; dayInMonth > lastDayNum; dayInMonth++){
    console.log("here!") // not displaying anything
}
```

What is stopping the for loop from executing the`console.log()` statement?

Comment: Obviously `dayInMonth > lastDayNum` is `false`, i.e 2<30.... Take a nap and try again

Comment: +1 for take a nap. Naps rock!

Comment: Thank you everyone! The perils of programming on coffee and no sleep...

Comment: +1 as you don't deserve to lose rep for being tired. Go to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong logical test (< rather than >);

```
for(; dayInMonth < lastDayNum; dayInMonth++){
    console.log("here!") // not displaying anything
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

`dayInMonth > lastDayNum` will never be greater

Answer (score 1):

`dayInMonth > lastDayNum` should be `dayInMonth <= lastDayNum`, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(dayInMonth; dayInMonth < lastDayNum; dayInMonth++){
    alert("here!") // not displaying anything
}​
```

You want < not >.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
dayInMonth < lastDayNum
```

A for loop is executed as long as the second parameter is true, not until it's false.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dayInMonth = 2,
    lastDayNum = 30;

console.log(dayInMonth, (dayInMonth > lastDayNum)); // displays "2 false"

for(dayInMonth; dayInMonth < lastDayNum; dayInMonth++){
    console.log("here!") // not displaying anything
}
```

Inside for <, not >